# Title for UIButton won't appear

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

So I am trying to create a custom UIBarButtonItem, but I can't for the life of me figure out why the title won't show. Maybe someone else can spot it :\

Here is the code I use to create the bar button:

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title normal:(UIImage *)normal highlighted:(UIImage *)highlight selected:(UIImage *)selected target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, normal.size.width, normal.size.height)];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setImage:normal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:selected forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button setImage:selected forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
}


self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem barButtonItemWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                                         normal:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_active.png"] 
                                                                    highlighted:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_highlight.png"] 
                                                                       selected:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_selected.png"] 
                                                                         target:self 
                                                                         action:@selector(popViewController)];
```

Any help would be appreciated!

P.S. This is in iOS 5 using ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

title and image are mutually exclusive properties in UIButton. If you want to have title with custom background then you should use backgroundImage property:

```
...
[button setBackgroundImage:normal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:selected forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setBackgroundImage:selected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
...
```

Comment: TY. I knew it was something really silly. Guess I should get to bed instead of staying up till 4 am! :\